# I keep receiving an "unexpected EOF while parsing" error and don't understand why

Tags: python, parsing, eof, leap-year

I am supposed to do a problem on leap years to test whether the year is a valid year for a leap year. It is a leap year if the year is divisible by 4, but not if divisible by 100 but is if divisible by 400. We were given a function with a list of dates that had years like 0007 so I had to strip the unwanted 0's. I keep receiving an "unexpected EOF while parsing" error and have no idea why. All of the dates are in the format "mm/dd/yyyy"

```
  from ListofDates import *
def main():
    dates = ListofDates()
    Result = ""
    for date in dates:
        stripped = date[6:].strip("0")
        if eval(stripped) % 4 == 0:
            if eval(stripped) % 400 == 0:
                Result = Result + "-"
            elif eval(stripped) % 100 == 0:
                Result = Result + str(date[9])
            else:
                Result = Result + "-"
        else:
            Result = Result + str(date[9])
    print (Result)
main()
```

Comment: The code you posted here has no such error; you have a *Python syntax error* it appears (the parser trying to read the Python source code you provide expected to find some more code).

Comment: Please post the *full traceback* of the error. What does `ListofDates()` do?

Comment: It might be a copy/paste error, but you have an indentation error with the import statement.  It's also worth checking that you aren't mixing tabs and spaces.  Execute the script with `python -tt` to check...

Comment: By the way, you should be using `float()` or `int()` to turn strings into numbers, not `eval()`.

Comment: You can get that error for a variety of reasons including a missing end paren `)`. The code you've shown us has no such problem and after fixing the indent on the first line, compiles just fine. The problem could be in the module you imported or maybe you didn't post quite the same code that failed. We asked for the stack trace to try to narrow down the error. Help us help you!